# how can i programmatically put a uicollectionview within an expanding uitableviewcell

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

i am trying to put a UICollectionview inside of an expanding uitableviewcell, but i keep getting errors. the collectionview is also suppose to take pictures and store them within the collectionview. i used this code:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"myCell";    
UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];  


[cell addTarget:self action:@selector(uploadPicture:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
return cell;
}

- (void)uploadPicture:(id)sender
{
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.allowsEditing = YES;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

the errors i am getting are "no visible @interface for UICollectionViewCell declares the selelctor addTarget:action:forControlEvents" in line 4. and line 5 "void method should not return value" and line 11 "no visible @interface for ExpandingCell declares the selector presentViewController:animated:completion"

i am desparate for help at this point. so thank you in advance if you do help.

Comment: Did you check documentation?

Comment: yes, it was no help.

Comment: How did you know about addTarget method? It's not in documentation for UICollectionViewCell.

Comment: i clicked the red error indicator and thats what it said. im not really sure what that means, so i have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Err you are dequeing cell in `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`. And its a void method, so you cant return a cell here.

Answer (score 0):

Quite a few issues here. 
Line 4 - you are in the didSelectItemAtIndexPath method, so you know the user has already touched the cell. You should not need to wire up a target action. Remove this line and call uploadPicture: directly.
Line 5 - didSelectItemAtIndexPath is a void method, so you should not try to return cell. Remove this line.
Line 11 - the error indicates your uploadPicture method is not within a view controller. Therefore it cannot present a view controller. You need to move this method to your view controller or refactor your code so that you present from within a view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to achieve the following:

1. User has a tableview, and when user taps on a row in table view, app presents an image picker
2. User selects a number of images from library
3. All selected images are then shown in a collection view which is embedded within the expanded cell of the tableview

If that assumption is correct, you have to:

1. implement didSelectRowAtIndexPath for the tableview instead of collectionview
2. Within this method, call the uploadPicture method
3. implement didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo of imagePickerController to get selected images
4. call cellForRowAtIndexPath of the tableview controller to create cell with collectionview having the selected images.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i am not as good at objective c as i need to be for this. so i am not sure what you mean in the first point. if you have time today maybe email me, and help me out? ( t.stac4@yahoo.com )